# Redirect to Mobile site?

Tags: javascript, .net

When the user join my site.. if they use mobile.. I want to redirect to the mobile site..

How can I do that with javascript or .net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this on your page load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

If Request.Browser("IsMobileDevice") = "True" Then
Response.Redirect("put url here", True)

End If

End Sub
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you'd compile a list of user-agent strings for mobile browsers and extract which patterns you want to handle. Then in your server code, send a 302 response header OR issue a page with a META refresh to your mobile URL.